# Grab images and set configuration of GenICam protocol in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, genicam

I have ContrasTech mars series camera that that connected with usb3 to pc and install iCentral app that can access camera.
I want to access camera and grab live images from it. I found that it uses GenICam protocol, but cannot find any useful documention in C# .Net.
In Vendor site there is [SDK](http://www.contrastech.com/en/service/005001.html) that contains some DLL files and libs but with no documentation.
For example

- MVSDKmd.lib
- HalconHDevelopAdapter
- List item
- Development\Include\GenICam\CAPI\SDK.h

I need to capture images and set configuration for these cameras in C# .NET.
Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user3865434- Have you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for a .NET GenICam library.
Maybe this one does the job:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/GenICam/

I don't know this camera vendor so I cannot tell anything about their API. I have used Basler and IDS cameras so far, both through their specific APIs, and Basler cameras also through GigE Vision by Matrox Imaging Library.
There are other powerful GigE Vision libraries (search for e.g. "GigE Vision SDK"), but they usually are not free.